# Selecting every row in a table without using limit?

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I'm using jdbc with mysql. I need to iterate over every row in a table (60,000 rows, table = InnoDB), and perform some processing on each.

Will mysql accept a query without a limit like that? In the simplest implementation, I simply select the entire table, and keep iterating the results while the cursor gives me more results:

```
PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM foo");
ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
while (rs.next()) {
    .. do stuff on each row ..
}
```

I can implement a paging query of course to do this in batches, but it'd be simpler to just do it as stated in the first approach. I wonder if mysql does this internally, or it tries to load the entire query result set into memory first?

Thanks

Comment: it loads it all up and blows up memory if it feels like it

Comment: _"Will mysql accept a query without a limit like that?"_ Why wouldn't it? Why don't you try it for yourself and see?

Comment: @DrewPierce Setting the fetchsize to `Integer.MIN_VALUE` won't blow your memory with MySQL JDBC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL is gonna run it and try its best for sure, or at least try to use our memory until it runs out. It's also interesting highlight in a few other points:

1. Even using LIMIT, MySQL Parser is still gonna do a fullscan in your table. LIMIT runs in one level after this process;
2. MySQL is gonna try to use your memory and if it is not enough, the Parser swaps it to the filesystem, which is much more slower and expensive in terms of performance;
3. Try to use indexes and WHERE CLAUSE to make the most of your queries. Surely you don't need to bring all that to your application layer;

Good luck!

Comment: Without an ORDER etc (as in the post), the RDBMS is free to return all the results from the table in pretty much any order it chooses - generally along it's physical layout. Likewise, if a LIMIT *was* supplied here, the RDBMS is free to returned said number of rows (but no more) in any manner it chooses. If there is no WHERE/ORDER/GROUP/etc clause then indices don't apply so there is no point to dread a "table scan" - it just has to read the data to return it.